# Allowing only float numbers, with one decimal point, AND A NEGATIVE SIGN (Python/Kivy/Regex)

Tags: python, regex, filter, compilation, textinput

Firstly, I would like to say I'm very new to the language, but already got pretty deep in my calculator app for simple physics equations. My plan is to make a home screen with one other calculation screen first, and once that is as good as I can get it to be, I will continue to the rest of the screens.

In this particular screen, (and probably most other ones I'll have to use this function) I've established a custom TextInput that only allows numbers 0-9 and one decimal point. However, I'm currently breaking my head trying to figure out how to include a NEGATIVE SIGN in to my allowed set of inputs.

Here's the code: (I found it open source, I understand the logistics, but I've yet to completely understand the re.compile function)

```
class FloatInput(TextInput):

    pat = re.compile('[^0-9]') <----THIS IS WHERE I TRIED TO ADD ^[+-]? w/ NO LUCK :(
    def insert_text(self, substring, from_undo=False):

        pat = self.pat

        if '.' in self.text:
            s = re.sub(pat, '', substring)


        else:
            s = '.'.join([re.sub(pat, '', s) for s in substring.split('.', 1)])


        return super(FloatInput, self).insert_text(s, from_undo=from_undo)
```

Comment: Please format your code properly, [click here to learn how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: You don't have to scream

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Python doc'n for the re module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html):

> If `-` is escaped (e.g. `[a\-z]`) or if it’s placed as the first or last character (e.g. `[-a]` or `[a-]`), it will match a literal `'-'`.

To get a pattern that matches anything but 0-9, - or +, you can use

```py
pat = re.compile('[^0-9\-+]')
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of replacing irrelevant characters from the string, would you like to consider if the user enters the number in the right format?

If so, please try with re.match and probe user to enter the right format until it gets right.

Try this code to match your requirement of -ve floating-point numbers

```
re.match('^-{0,1}[0-9]*(.[0-9]+){0,1}$', '-1.1000008')
```

I tried a couple of negative examples and tested. Please feel free to modify if anything is missing.

A couple of info regarding this regex string

```
^ -> starts with
$ -> ends with
{0,1} -> 0 - 1 occurrence only
* -> Zero or more times
+ -> One or more times
() -> group
```

You can put this string in re.compile too.
re.match outputs match if any, else None

Cheers,

Comment: Hello, just a follow-up question, can you assert only one negative sign allowed (in the re.compile)? or would I have to change my entire code? Also, re.match didn't seem to work out for me - as the code stands, I would probably have to modify it more than just sticking to what I have.

Comment: Hi Gleb, The previous code takes care of just one negative sign (zero or one). You might need to check if there is a match, then continue with the computation, else, ask the user to add the right number. You can put the match string in re.compile().